org-mode export to latex/pdf: Indent text depending on heading level?
Would it be possible for elements under a heading (text, lists, tables, images) to be indented depending on level of an org mode heading? E.g. text under heading level 1 would be most to the left and subsequent headings would be indented further to the right when exported from org mode to latex/pdf?
my current headers.tex included in org document: https://pastebin.com/9nYe45bP
org mode document:
#+LATEX_HEADER: \input{/home/<USER>/latex/headers.tex}
#+OPTIONS: \n:t
#+OPTIONS: H:6
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+LATEX_COMPILER: xelatex

* heading 1
text indented to the level of heading 1
|sample table|sample table|
|sample table|sample table|
[[./sample-image.png]]
** heading 2
text indented to the level of heading 2
** heading 3
text indented to the level of heading 3
** heading 4
text indented to the level of heading 4

command to export org mode to tex and pdf using emacs:
emacsclient --eval '(progn (find-file "sample.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))'


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing...

I've updated the answer with more details of my setup - it's using emacs, but pandoc would work just as well. I hope that it's any clearer - intention is to just get text/image/table indented to corresponding heading levels

As I mentioned in your question on Emacs SE, you should delete all Org mode details when you post here. Just as we don't generally do TeX on Emacs SE, the people on TeX SE don't generally do Emacs. You need to translate your question from Org mode to TeX.

please note that questions shouldn't rely on external links. please post code for a complete example here so that your question is self-contained and remains useful in the future. (also, pastebin has become one of the more obnoxious pastebin sites, but that not really relevant here.)

Headings in Org mode are translated to sectioning structure (depending on configuration): in the default "article" configuration, one-star headings are translated to sections, two-star headings to subsections, and so on: subsubsections, paragraphs and subparagraphs. So what the OP is looking for (AFAICT) is indentation of each subsection in a section, indentation of a subsubsection in a subsection and so on.

Maybe something like this?

Thank you all, yes @NickD exactly like in this example - that is really helpful. I will close this question and if mentioned in the future refer to your question (with limited knowledge of TeX I would struggle to convert the question properly).

I realize that's unrelated, I will close the question soon, but just out of curiosity, what would you recommend as an alternative to pastebin @cfr?

see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/List_of_applications/Internet#Pastebin_services. I generally use https://0x0.st/ and haven't tried termbin.com, which is the other recommendation. However, the Arch wiki is generally reliable and if something like this was wrong it would cause lots of annoyance on the forums very, very quickly. which is to say, I'm sure termbin.com is also fine, but can personally recommend 0x0.st. (using pastebin.com on Arch's forums will almost always mean you have to correct your post before anybody will look at it.)

Thank you, I will start using 0x0.st cat <FILE> | curl -F "file=@-" https://0x0.st
